# Modifying a C struct in VB.NET

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, interopservices

I'm trying to use someone else's DLL coded in C in my VB.NET application.
My VB.NET application sends some callbacks pointers to the DLL and DLL then calls back to functions inside my VB.NET application.

The DLL is calling a function inside VB.NET and passing a pointer of a C struct.
My VB.NET application has to modify the struct values, so the DLL can work with the new struct values. I can't modify the DLL's code because it is someone else's DLL.

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t index;
  uint8_t value;
  uint8_t leds[4];
  struct {
    int8_t x;
    int8_t y;
    int8_t z;
  } input[10];
} REPORT;
```

My VB.NET structure definition is

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure INPUTS
    Public x As SByte
    Public y As SByte
    Public z As SByte
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure REPORT
    Public index As Byte
    Public value As Byte

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)>
    Public leds() As Byte


    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=10)>
    Public input() As INPUTS

    Sub New(numleds As Integer, numinputs As Integer)
        ReDim Me.leds(numleds)
        ReDim Me.input(numinputs)
    End Sub
End Structure
```

My VB.NET delegate is declared as

```
Public Delegate Function Del_Read(ByVal lpReport As IntPtr) As Byte
```

vb.net sends vb.net delegate to C DLL

```
Public Ext_Read As Del_Read = New Del_Read(AddressOf Read)
SendToDll(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Ext_Read))
```

My VB.NET function is declared as

```
 Public Function Read(ByVal lpReport As IntPtr) As Byte

        Dim report As New REPORT(3, 9)

        report.index = 0
        report.value = 5   
        report.input(0).x = 90
        report.input(0).y = 0
        report.input(0).z = 0

        report.input(1).x = 180
        report.input(1).y = 0
        report.input(1).z = 0

        Dim size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(report)
        Dim ptrMem As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size)
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(report, ptrMem, False)

        Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(size - 1) {}
        Marshal.Copy(ptrMem, bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrMem)

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, lpReport, size)

        Return 1
    End Function
```

I get the following error when the function ends and nothing else.

```
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I have tried different codes, like `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or declaring the function as

```
Public Function Read(ByRef localReport As REPORT) As Byte
```

Even though the code compiles just fine, the error is because of Marshal.StructureToPtr somehow, because if I change the code to the one as below, I get no errors and the DLL obtains the new values. The only problem is that I have to calculate manually the offsets for `report.input(0)`, `report.input(1)`, etc.

```
Public Function Read(ByVal lpReport As IntPtr) As Byte

    Dim report As New REPORT(3, 9)

    report.index = 0
    report.value = 5

    Dim size As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(report)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(size - 1) {}

    bytes(0) = report.index
    bytes(1) = report.value

    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, lpReport, size)

    Return 1
End Function
```

Any ideas why the code fails? Or a simpler way to modify the structure sent from the DLL?

Comment: The code is fairly hacked to death, but it just takes Marshal.StructureToPtr(report, lpReport, False).  Exactly what the C function pointer looks like is important.

Comment: Hi, yes i also tried Marshal.StructureToPtr(report, lpReport, False) but it fails as well at runtime when the functions end with the same error message. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 'This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: according to the author of the dll the c function pointer is   
`typedef  uint8_t (_stdcall *API_Read)(REPORT *);`  
`API_Read Read=NULL;`  
  
`REPORT report;`  
`Read(&report);`

Comment: There's nothing wrong.  You need support from the author, send him a small repro project.

Comment: yes i will send him one. the code works, or seems to work (just tested it for a few seconds) if i don't use Marshal.StructureToPtr(...) and manually copy the structure to the array of bytes, and then copy the array of bytes to lpReport. but will have to calculate the offsets manually.  the C dll is allocating the report structure in the stack, maybe thats why Marshal.StructureToPtr complains after the function ends... i cant seem to find the Marshal.StructureToPtr implementation using ILSPy the code just says external but doesnt says where the code is for analysis.

Comment: sorry guys i have fix it, code is good as Hans Passant suggested, the problem was with another bad delegate callback declaration that are being called right after Read() returns to C DLL, sorry for waisting your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because author says problem was due to a defect. See author's comment "sorry guys i have fix it, code is good as Hans Passant suggested, the problem was with another bad delegate callback declaration that are being called right after Read() returns to C DLL, sorry for waisting your time. – Messias Nov 11 '14 at 23:51"